# How to use React-native-super-grid as a Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

```
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';


class Grid extends React.Component () {
    
export default function Example() {
```

I just write until here..
But, don't work...
What I have to do ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a valid response from the component. For example, if you want to make a Component using FlatGrid you can use this structure:

```js
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';


export default function Example() {
  return(  
    <View>
      <FlatGrid
        itemDimension={130}
        data={[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text>{item}</Text>)}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

And also I see you are using a class ***class*** named **Grid** that is extending the **`React.Component ()`** and from your code I see you are not importing the `React` from `react` so in order to use the class you have to use:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';

export default class Grid extends React.Compoment {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <FlatGrid
          itemDimension={130}
          data={[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text>{item}</Text>)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```